# Idempiere UpdateAction webservice is returning error message: cannot set column message

Tags: adempiere, idempiere

I created a webservice to update a column value in a table. While calling it using SOAP request xml, getting error message like: Cannot set value of column.

For users table, I am able to call similar webservice without any issue. But, this issue is coming with particular table. In which case, this message might come? Cannot set value of column.

Comment: Can you provide your sample request and how you have configured your web service security?

Answer (score 1):

Check the log on the server, the cause of that failure is logged in SEVERE level.

Comment: Hi CarlosRuiz, I gone through the logs but couldn't find anything related to this call.

Comment: Hi @DDphp, checking the code is possible the saving is not returning a clear error, so is not logged, or that your log level is uppper than SEVERE.

The information is too little to be able to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This exception if you are using non supported value. If your field is boolean type then use Y or N as value.